# ImportError: cannot import name 'gutenburg'

Tags: python-3.x

I have downloaded NLTK package already.I have gutenburg module in nltk_data also

```
from nltk.corpus import gutenburg
    sample=gutenburg.raw("bible.kjv.txt")
    print(sample[0:10])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the name is `gutenberg` instead of `gutenburg`.

Comment: Yesh..i am so poor at finding the differences.Thanks